# Finding $EX$ of a density function (integrating $\ln u$ over infinity)

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I've been given a density function as:

> $f(x) = 1/4e^{-|x|/2}$ where $-\infty < x < \infty$

and need to show that $EX = 0$

I understand that to find $EX$ I must calculate $\int xf(x)~dx$ using the limits of the function.

I get to a point where I must find $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ln u~du$ and it turns out that this diverges. I'm stuck as to how this comes out as 0.

Answer (score 1):

The required integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx$ converges. Note that the function $\frac{x}{4}e^{-|x|/2}$ is an **odd** function, so the integral is $0$.

Alternately, calculate separately $\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{x}{4}e^{-|x|/2}\,dx$ and $\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{4}e^{-|x|/2}\,dx$.

We recognize the second integral as one-half of the mean of an exponentially distributed random variable with $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$. So this integral is $1$. For the integral from $-\infty$ to $0$, make the substitution $y=-x$. We end up with $-1$.